# no such file to load -- config/initializers/airbrake (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote a simple ROR application and i raised an exception using airbrake. This is my code as follows

```
require 'airbrake'
require 'config/initializers/airbrake'

begin
  raise "Serious problems happened"
  params = {
  :api_key       => Airbrake.api_key,
  :error_message => 'Notification',
  :backtrace     => caller,
  :parameters    => {},
  :session       => {}
       }
rescue => e
         Airbrake.notify(:error_class => "Special Error", :error_message => "Spe
cial Error: #{e.message}",  :parameters => params)
end
```

When i run the above code, i'm getting the following exception

```
/root/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/cus
tom_require.rb:55:in `require': no such file to load -- config/initializers/airb
rake (LoadError)
        from /root/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from sample.rb:2:in `<main>''
```

But i have airbrake.rb in config/initializers, I don't know why the path is not taken.

What could be the issue here

Answer (score 0):

You don't generally require your initializers explicitly. Code in config/initializers/ gets automatically loaded by your application.

Furthermore, if you've set up your Airbrake initializer properly, you can use a handy little helper called `notify_airbrake` to fire off Airbrake traces:

```
begin
  ...
rescue Exception => e
  notify_airbrake e
end
```

That's all there is to it!